# Does any one have WiringPiGpioInterrupt working in Tomcat7?

Tags: java, gpio

Does any one have WiringPiGpioInterrupt working in Tomcat7?

I get a crash every time I push a button.

see PI4J [Issues](https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/issues/) 176,180 and 184.

Is there any other option?
Do I need to restart again in Python?

```
package com.na7kr.Interrupt;


import com.na7kr.GPIOController.GPIOController;
import com.na7kr.Utils.Utils;
import com.na7kr.rpi_gpio_controller.Rpi_gpio_controllerApplicationUI;

import com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio;
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.GpioInterruptCallback;

public class Interrupt {
    Rpi_gpio_controllerApplicationUI mApplication = new Rpi_gpio_controllerApplicationUI(); // NO_UCD
                                                                                            // (use
                                                                                            // private)

    // ***************************************
    public synchronized void GetInput1(int trigerpin, int outputpin) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("<--Pi4J--> GPIO interrupt test program");

        // setup wiringPi
        if (Gpio.wiringPiSetup() == -1) {
            System.out.println(" ==>> GPIO SETUP FAILED");
            return;
        }

        Gpio.pinMode(1, Gpio.INPUT);
        Gpio.pinMode(2, Gpio.INPUT);

        Gpio.pullUpDnControl(1, Gpio.PUD_UP);
        Gpio.pullUpDnControl(2, Gpio.PUD_UP);

        Gpio.wiringPiISR(1, Gpio.INT_EDGE_FALLING, new GpioInterruptCallback() {
            @Override
            public void callback(int pin) {

                System.out.println(" ==>> GPIO PIN " + pin + " - INTERRUPT DETECTED");
                Utils.Output_WriteDebug(true, "1");

                GPIOController.INSTANCE.mGPIOPins[0].toggle();
                mApplication.refreshGPIOPinState();
                Utils.Output_WriteDebug(true, "2");
            }
        });
        Gpio.wiringPiISR(2, Gpio.INT_EDGE_FALLING, new GpioInterruptCallback() {
            @Override
            public void callback(int pin) {
                System.out.println(" ==>> GPIO PIN " + pin + " - INTERRUPT DETECTED");
                Utils.Output_WriteDebug(true, "3");
                GPIOController.INSTANCE.mGPIOPins[0].toggle();
                mApplication.refreshGPIOPinState();
                Utils.Output_WriteDebug(true, "4");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Kevin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues with your post.  Please edit your question and post your code here.

Comment: Added the code as requested

Comment: Now that you have done that, it's a good quality question and I have up voted it.